# Python ZMQ and multiprocessing causes zmq.error.ZMQError: Interrupted system call

Tags: python, multiprocessing, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a Python script where I'm binding several (e.g., 5) ZMQ receiver sockets like so:

```
receiver_1 = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
receiver_1.bind("tcp://*:5555")
...
receiver_5 = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
receiver_5.bind("tcp://*:5559")

receivers = [receiver_1, ..., receiver_5]
```

Then I start some Google Compute Engine instances, and they connect the corresponding sender sockets.

I'd like to pull from these sockets in parallel, and so I'm attempting to do that with a multiprocessing pool. The code looks something like this:

```
def recv_result(i):
    result_str = receivers[i].recv()
    return cPickle.loads(result_str)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
while True:
    results = pool.map(recv_result, [i for i in range(len(receivers))])
    # break when all results have been received
    ...
```

The error I'm getting when I run my script looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File ...
    results = pool.map(recv_result, [i for i in range(len(receivers))])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 227, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 528, in get
    raise self._value
zmq.error.ZMQError: Interrupted system call
```

I've also tried implementing the same functionality using multiprocessing.Process, but I get essentially the same error, though in a much messier fashion.

What I'm trying to do is to more efficiently receive all of the results from my GCE instances, as I've found this to be the bottleneck in my script (in my current working implementation, I have only one receiver socket, and it receives results from all of the GCE instances serially). If anyone could point me to the bug in my current code, or any suggestions for a better way to achieve my goal, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Few hints:

- good you use ZeroMQ - it can do a lot for you without writing too much code
- do not overoptimize. You will not gain anything by multiprocessing/threading for ZeroMQ communication, it is already very fast and able to exchange incredible amount of messages
- if using threading/multiprocessing, never share zmq context, it must be private for the thread, otherwise it breaks. This is probably the cause of your exception.
- if current code uses blocking zeromq sends and receive, change it to nonblocking. Check how to use polling.

Comment: My first thought was "why multithreading"?  I agree, this smells of premature optimization. If you need to handle the results in parallel, receive the messages and then pass them to a worker.  Receiving the messages serially should be fine.

Comment: @Jason Nice think on ZeroMQ is, that it handles the messages in parallel without you having to care about. Of course, Python code in one thread will consume them one by one - serially. On the other hand, if there is need for more workers in multiple processes or threads, zeromq serves that excellently. I wanted to stress out, there is no need to set up more channels for messages to get higher throughput.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! I've seen a lot of similar answers elsewhere while doing my own research, and it just seems like most of the latency introduced while running my script across many GCE instances as opposed to locally comes from actually collecting the results from the instances (when computing the results aren't the bottleneck, running locally is about 10x faster). I realize what I'm doing may not be the best way to fix this, do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: """if using threading/multiprocessing, never share zmq context, it must be private for the thread, otherwise it breaks. This is probably the cause of your exception."""  Saves Lifes!! :-)